# RTSP stream not understood by VLC: this bitstream does not contain Vorbis audio data

Tags: gstreamer, vlc, rtsp, rtp

I have an audio-only RTSP stream, I can play this stream with the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test" ! rtpvorbisdepay ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink
```

However, when I try to open it with VLC this way:

```
vlc rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
```

It doesn't play any sound (although it does identify the length of the stream and "plays") and it outputs the following to the console:

```
[00007f9ebc04fa80] vorbis decoder error: this bitstream does not contain Vorbis audio data
[00007f9ebc04fa80] vorbis decoder error: this bitstream does not contain Vorbis audio data
[00007f9ebc04fa80] vorbis decoder error: this bitstream does not contain Vorbis audio data
```

...etc

Pipeline used to play the stream:

```
str = g_strdup_printf ("( "
    "filesrc location=%s ! oggdemux "
    "! rtpvorbispay name=pay0 pt=96 " ")", argv[1]);
```

Help?

Comment: This really doesn't seem like a C language question, and is a bit light on any other information.  All I can offer is noticing that the parameters you are passing to gst-launch-1.0 are different to those in your "pipeline" string.  Also, did you intend to change `rtpvorbisdepay` to `rtpvorbispay`, or is that a typo?

Comment: I also see you explicitly specify `oggdemux` (as in OGG-Vorbis), whereas the working version uses `autoaudiosink`, which I presume detects the audio format.  Could it be that your stream is not actually a Vorbis stream?

Comment: @paddy aye you are right, it's written in C but barely pertinent. It goes from RTP `pay(load)` to `depay` (at the client side). Also that's a good observation, decodebin is actually doing its part automatically but it works the same if I use `vorbisdec` which is more specific. Sorry if this is all too specific to the library that I am using and thus hard to help with.